# Add code behind to template in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

We're adding functionality to an Umbraco site.  We do not have access to the c# of the templates and all we can do is create user controls and add them to the pages.

The original developers used the Umbraco UI to do the entire site so all we have access to is the template and its html but not the code behind.

What we now would like to do is add some code into one or two of the existing pages.

Can we do this?  Can we add a class file that has a particular namespace etc that will then execute the page_load method when the template starts?

Sorry if I'm being a little vague

Answer (score 1):

You can use masterpage the same way as you would use an aspx file, just create the template pages in the GUI and open the project in visual studio.

To create the codefile there is a utility that will do some of the work for you http://umbracocs.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The template in Umbraco is really a master page. Umbraco has a single aspx page (default.aspx) that is the entry point for all requests. So you can't add code to a template in the sense you would add it into the code behind of a page.

Can't you just create a user control having the code that you need (no ui) and just add it to the tempate through a macro?

Comment: we can but we would like the ability to call one user control from another and for that we need to be able to delegate from one to the other and the only place i can think to link them up is in the code behind of the page

Comment: you can call one user control from another (you just need to register it at the top of the .ascx page).

Comment: our two controls are essentially two macros in umbraco and sit in different content placeholders within the template.  so i don't this that'll work.  sounds to me that what we are trying to do is not possible with our umbraco setup

Comment: yeah, but behind those macros are actual .NET user controls I assume - so what prevents you from using one in the other (possibly based on a control property)?

Comment: what's preventing it is that between the two controls is text that the client can update so we have two macros on the page and we cannot contain the second within the first.  so we can't have a single macro with both user controls in it.  or am i really missing the point here?

Comment: i don't understand your goal then - I thought you wanted 'the ability to call one user control from another': that does that mean in your context